# How to evaluate this improper integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve some improper integrals and I solved this improper integral by many ways
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

But I'm wondering how can I solve a similar question but if we have
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ x^p \cos x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Where $-1<p<1$

I think we will get some terms of $\cos( \frac{\pi p}{2}) \ $ and
$\sin (\frac{\pi p}{2}) \ $

I also think that maybe we will get an incomplete gamma function
am I right?
Please provide a full solution as I stucked alot in this integral

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\sin \left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right) \Gamma (p-1) \,
   _1F_2\left(1;1-\frac{p}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{p}{2};\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \pi 
   \cosh (1) \sec \left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right)$$

Comment: The methods I know to evaluate the first integral are Feynman's trick and contour integration. Anything else you know about?